# Add status "pending to approve" Odoo 12

Tags: model, odoo, odoo-12

I want to add the status of the quotes, I see that there are 3 at the beginning: quote, budget sent and notice for sales order. I need to add a state that says "pending to approve" that only the Management user approves it. I know what I can do through inherit, but where is the model and which module is the one I should place as a dependency.

Can somebody help me?

**UPDATE:** I already found it. And I've already located the field that I want to add more states. However, being new, I can not understand all this code. Can someone explain to me please?

`state = fields.Selection([
        ('draft', 'Quotation'),
        ('sent', 'Quotation Sent'),
        ('sale', 'Sales Order'),
        ('done', 'Locked'),
        ('cancel', 'Cancelled'),
        ], string='Status', readonly=True, copy=False, index=True, track_visibility='onchange', track_sequence=3, $
    date_order = fields.Datetime(string='Order Date', required=True, readonly=True, index=True, states={'draft': [$
    validity_date = fields.Date(string='Validity', readonly=True, copy=False, states={'draft': [('readonly', False$
        help="Validity date of the quotation, after this date, the customer won't be able to validate the quotatio$
    is_expired = fields.Boolean(compute='_compute_is_expired', string="Is expired")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quotations are sale orders that are not yet confirmed. You can check for record model from multiple hints, for example:

1. from URL, once you go to quotations menu you get the url like following `/web?#view_type=list&model=sale.order&action=264&menu_id=166`. Here model parameter is `model=sale.order`, so you have to look for model definition of `sale.order`.
2. Go to your required view, click debug menu -> Edit action, look for the field object, also in this case `sale.order`.

Once you get what model you need to work on, you can look for models definition by searching `_name.*sale.order` or replace `sale.order` with whatever model you need to inherit.

In this particular case, your required module is defined in the `sale` module. So you can start by inheriting `sale.order` and putting `sale` as your custom modules dependency. Also keep in mind, odoo built in modules are sometime inherited, so there may be some case where you want to inherit functionality of a model but the `fields` or `views` you want to inherit is defined in the child module of `sale`, for example some of `sale.order` models functionality is defined in `sale_stock` module by mean of inheritance. In that case, you have to set `sale_stock` as dependency.

Comment: Thank you, I already found it. And I've already located the field that I want to add more states. However, being new, I can not understand all this code. Can someone explain to me please?

Comment: That would be way too much to explain on StackOverflow. Try to get your hands on the [official Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/), online tutorials or buy a book about Odoo development.